# Connotation of word shrewd

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, connotations

I did a lot of research on internet regarding the connotation of word shrewd. It can have negative as well as positive connotation.It depends on the context of the passage. For instance,

> A shrewd real estate agent
>
> A shrewd business man

Another usage of shrewd is for decisions, policies, judgements etc. Well, I was looking for this particular usage on dictionary and found [this.](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shrewd)
Second usage has confused me a bit as it is mentioned that shrewd activities are marked as artful and cunning practices. Now the word cunning has purely negative connotation. So I want to know how do native speakers use this word? Specially I am confused about its usage with activities. **For Instance - a shrewd policy or a shrewd decision.** An example for negative usage of shrewd could be this sentence

> The union was known for its shrewd negotiating tactics. (calculating, underhanded)
>
> On Twitter, he said it was a “brutal conspiracy and a shrewd scheme” that allowed Mr. Modi’s “suit-boot friends to convert their black money into white”.

Comment: It's a declining usage anyway, so as a *learner* you might want to take the easy way out and just ignore this word. But as you correctly say, *connotation depends on the context*. It also varies from person to person (for many different reasons). *On average*, if you see references to a *shrewd policy* or a *shrewd decision*, they'll be "approving". But as a question for ELL, it's Off Topic POB (Primarily Opinion-Based).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica...Sometimes I ask well researched questions and still they are downvoted. As a non-native speaker of english language my questions cannot match the question level of native speakers. Its disappointing sometimes.Now should I delete this question?

Comment: Well, someone's upvoted my comment, but despite what I wrote there, I *didn't* vote to close the question myself (and so far nor has anyone else). I can understand you might want to delete the question if you're getting ***downvotes*** (which may reduce your reputation points, thus restricting your use of this site). But that's not happening, so I don't think you have any good reason for deleting it. Just because I wasn't very "encouraging" above doesn't mean you should abandon all hope! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica..I have decided to follow your first advice. As a learner I must learn to distinguish between what is useful and what is not. I am going to skip this word for now. One last question for you, Do you know any resource where I can look for words which are currently used. Any website or book will be best.

Comment: I was going to suggest you could use Google NGrams to see if there's been a significant "usage shift" for, say, [***a shrewd man***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+shrewd+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20shrewd%20man%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20shrewd%20man%3B%2Cc0) But although *that* one shows a steady drop in popularity over the past century (exactly as I'd expect), things are completely different with...

Comment: ...the chart for [***a shrewd businessman***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+shrewd+businessman&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20shrewd%20businessman%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20shrewd%20businessman%3B%2Cc0). Personally, I think Anglophone culture over the past century has increasingly come to be contemptuous of the commerce, industry, and economic realities sustaining our civilisation, which explains *that* oddity. But you'd need to be a bit of a sociologist as well as a linguist to figure that one out!

Comment: I *did* just vote to close this question as lacking research. I'm not saying that you didn't do research, but you should include *in the question itself* what research you did that leads you to think that *shrewd* can have a negative connotation. Also, I very much disagree that *cunning* has a "purely negative" connotation. So, you might be getting a wrong impression on several fronts. But you should provide clear examples that support your assumptions. There might be specific contexts where the meaning is clear rather than simply a matter of opinion—but simply asking each of us is subjective.

Comment: @Jason Bassford...I have edited my question to add some sentences which I think have negative connotation. A simple google search and even multiple answers on SE confirm about the negative connotation of word cunning. I did not add so many things in my question to make it look simple and not loaded with examples and information. My intention was not at all to get opinions.  Sometimes some words add a lot of confusion for non native speakers.

Comment: @SudhirSharma I still don't agree that *shrewd negotiating tactics* are bad. They're good. I don't think that *calculating* is negative either. And I definitely disagree that *underhanded* has any place there as a synonym … As for "a brutal conspiracy and a shrewd scheme," that's just two different things. It doesn't mean they are equated with each other. For instance, something that combines both of my points is this: *The philanthropist was known for her shrewd business savvy and investment in charities*. Or: *His cunning plan was smart, and good for everyone.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I disagree slightly with FumbleFingers. I believe shrewd is in regular usage. Per https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shrewd&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshrewd%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshrewd%3B%2Cc0, its usage has been slightly declining over the past 40 years, but it is, in no way, archaic.

On to the connotation. Shrewd does not imply underhanded or cheating. For example, a shrewd legislator isn't blackmailing people. She is using her knowledge of parliamentary procedure in order to increase her chances of getting her agenda passed into law. If you were of the opposite political party, you might crinkle your nose in disgust at her shrewdness, but only because she's not on your side.

Cunning is not a direct synonym, as cunning usually includes misrepresentation/lying, which shrewd usually does not include. For example, someone making $1 million selling vitamins that he implies helps with Covid 19 might be referred to as "cunning". Whereas a shrewd businessman would be someone who bought stock in Zoom the minute they heard of the outbreak. Both are making money on human misery, but there is, for most people, a distinct moral difference.

I would also agree with FumbleFingers that the phrase "shrewd businessman" might have a negative connotation for some, but that this has more to do with the "businessman" aspect. At least in the US, there is a significant portion of the population who see business as primarily exploitative, so someone who is very good at it must be morally questionable.